# Custom Search - How can I run JavaScript with a Salesforce 'Field Merge' to search on-click and return a result in a small popup?

Tags: javascript, uitextfield, salesforce, google-search

I'm using Salesforce and am trying to create a custom button to return the time based on a lead's ZIP code.

The buttons allow for on-click JavaScript. Is there any way I can use Google Custom Search to do the following:

The JavaScript can contain field merges (can automatically fill in the lead zip code). I would like, on button click, to return the time that appears at the top of a Google search when you search, for example, "Time (insert zip code here)" in a small pop up that can be clicked out of by clicking "Okay".

Any ideas?